# How to mock an abstract class using the decorator pattern and containing a constructor that takes an instance of itself

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

First, I want to clarify that this question is not a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367568/c-sharp-how-to-properly-unit-test-a-class-that-follows-a-decorator-pattern) because the situation is different when you have an abstract class.

My situation is that there exists a base class

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
     public FooBase(FooBase inner) { /* ... */ }

     public virtual void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

which is in a different assembly and I want to mock the behavior of `DoSomething()`. The problem is that if I try to create a mock

```
public class MockFoo : FooBase
{
    public MockFoo(...) : base(/*I have to put a FooBase in here*/) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I can't pass a `new MockFoo()` into `base` because it'll cause an infinite recursion. Any other ideas I have (such as creating another `MockFooOuter`) can't get around the infinite recursion problem.

Comment: Can the inner be null?

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: You need to show a better example of the target class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nkosi. You need to pass any (like suggested null) value to `base` that will not cause the exception in `FooBase` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a decorator you don't have to mock the decorated method `DoSomething` but the *whole* decorated class.

First of all you have to fix your class design and Decorator implementation:
right now the decorator accepts an instance of his own decorator type in the constructor which doesn't make sense. If it is a decorator it must accept an instance of the *decorated* type instead.
This means you have to introduce an interface for all the decorated types to implement. In this example it's named `IDecorated`.

The goal is to have a unit test that looks like this:

```
public class UnitTest
{
  public void TestDecorator()
  {
    IDecorated mockOfIDecorated = new DecoratedMock();
    DecoratorBase decoratorBaseTest = new DecoratorBaseTest(mockOfIDecorated);
    // Use decoratorBaseTest instance to test its public members
  }
}
```

To make mocking possible introduce an interface of the decorated type:

```
public interface IDecorated
{
  void DoSomething();
}
```

This will change and fix the signature of the constructor of the decorator type. Also don't make the implementation of the decorator's `DoSomething` virtual as this can lead to undesired behavior (e.g. the extending class forgets to delegate calls to the decorated type instance). Therefore the `virtual` has been removed. To make the extended behavior overrideable for subtypes just add an abstract method:

```
public abstract class DecoratorBase : IDecorated
{
  private IDecorated decorated;

  // The decorator should always accept an abstract type 
  // or interface of the type to be decorated
  public DecoratorBase(IDecorated decorated)
  {
    this.decorated = decorated;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // Delegate calls to the decorated class instance and ...
    this.decorated.DoSomething();

    // ... add functionality by invoking additional members. 
    // Making this member abstract adds customization for subtypes
    DoSomethingToExtendTheDecoratedBehavior();
  }

  public object DoSomethingDecoratorSpecific()
  {
  }

  protected abstract void DoSomethingToExtendTheDecoratedBehavior();
}
```

Since you cannot test an abstract class directly you need to provide a test implementation which can be instantiated by the test class:

```
public class DecoratorBaseTest : DecoratorBase
{
  public DecoratorBaseTest(IDecorated mockOfIDecorated) : base(mockOfIDecorated) { /* ... */ }

  #region Overrides of DecoratorBase

  protected override void DoSomethingToExtendTheDecoratedBehavior()
  {
    // Do nothing here because the unit test 
    // tests only public members of DecoratorBase 
  }

  #endregion
}
```

The mocked type of `IDecorated`. Invoking `DoSomething()` on this type does nothing:

```
public class DecoratedMock : IDecorated
{
  #region Implementation of IDecorated

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // Do nothing since this is a mock
  }

  #endregion
}
```

Now that the Decorator implementation is fixed, you can easily test the decorator class.